# Package installation of Keras in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.5, packaging, keras

Python 3.5, I am trying to find command to install a Keras Deep Learning package for Anaconda. The command `conda install -c keras` does not work, can anyone answer Why it doesn't work?

Comment: 'conda install -c kersa' should be 'conda install -c keras' ?

Comment: @linpingta yes and "CondaValueError: Value error: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or - - file"

Comment: I was able to install Keras using the steps listed at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47498448/896802).

Answer (score 3):

The specific answer to the question is that the `-c` option to the `conda` command specifies a *channel to search* for the package or packages you want to install.

> -c CHANNEL, --channel CHANNEL
>
> Additional channel to search for packages. These are URLs searched in the order they are given
>   (including file:// for local directories). Then, the defaults or
>   channels from .condarc are searched (unless
>   --override-channels is given). You can use 'defaults' to get the default packages for conda, and 'system' to get the system packages,
>   which also takes .condarc into account. You can also use any name and
>   the .condarc channel_alias value will be prepended. The default
>   channel_alias is http://conda.anaconda.org/.

Your command `conda install -c keras` specifies a channel called `keras` (on the default channel_alias url) but doesn't then specify any packages to install, so that's why you get the `Value error: too few arguments` error.

As Madhu Babu's answer notes, keras is available on the conda-forge channel so the correct command is

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to install keras

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

this is according to the documentation
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras

Comment: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras isn't keras documentation, it's just a page for the conda-forge package

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to Keras as well as Ubuntu and environments. However I think I've found a way. Create the conda env just like you would while installing Tensorflow (or even Theano).

Enter the env using 
source activate

Then use 
git clone https://github.com/fchollet/keras.git

Then enter keras folder and do
python setup.py install
(without the sudo)
- If any permissions error use chmod 777 recursively

Answer (score -2):

Navigate to `Anaconda installation folder/Scripts` and install with `pip` command

Comment: Can you Clarify how you access the Folder and how to locate it? My installation directory *"~/anaconda3/"* has no Scripts folder? Do you mean somehow in Anaconda browser (Anaconda Navigator)  to install or in system's Bash?