# How to clean iPython environment so I can start over with Jupyter and Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Over the past couple years I've `pip installed` lots of things without knowing what I was doing. All of a sudden, I am getting this error when I run a snippet in a Python 2.7 Jupyter Notebook:

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

When I run this in Terminal: [`which -a python python 3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33175893/896802)... I get:

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro-2:~ sambrand$ which -a python python3
//anaconda/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

I *think* this is showing that I have Python in a few places, which might explain why my standard libraries (eg. matplotlib) aren't being found in the Python environment that I want to use.

**My ideal result:**

Ultimately, I just want to clean up my environment and start from scratch so that I can use Keras, Tensorflow, and all Anaconda packages with Python 3 as my default when I open a Jupyter Notebook.

Additionally, I'd like any subsequent `pip install` from the terminal to update what I'm using in Jupyter.

From what I gather, [this kind of bewilderment about Python environment](https://twitter.com/amuellerml/status/932637063748444160) is a fairly common issue, so I hope this post proves helpful.

Comment: Why do you care what happens in a Python 2.7 notebook if your goal is to get Python 3 notebooks working right?  Can you import matplotlib from within a Python 3 notebook?

Comment: You really should look at using a virtual environment.

Comment: @BrenBarn Just now got a Python 3 notebook working. But cannot import matplotlib from within it. (Thanks!)

Comment: @coldspeed that's what the tensorflow docs suggest. Meanwhile [this guy](http://www.informit.com/store/deep-learning-with-tensorflow-livelessons-applications-9780134770857) says use Docker. So I'm going with option 3 for the moment and trying to get most basic setup installed first. I'm probably not doing this very intelligently.

Comment: @samthebrand to use matplotlib you need to install it with pip see the docs https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html

Answer (score 14):

Having a lot of python versions on the same machine is quite a common situation. To clean up your `python` you need to do the following steps:

0. Keep in mind that as for OSX 10.15, "native" `python` version in still 2.7. It lives in `/usr/bin/`. (Actual path is `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/` but it's the same thing.) If you want to roll back to the *clean* system `python` environment, you need to delete everything else.
1. First of all you need to find all other pythons. On my machine it was like this:

   ````
   $ which -a python python3
   /Users/yura/anaconda3/bin/python # <- Anaconda
   /opt/local/bin/python            # <- ports
   /opt/local/bin/python            # <- ports
   /opt/local/bin/python            # <- ports
   /opt/local/bin/python            # <- ports
   /usr/bin/python                  # <- "native"
   ~/anaconda3/bin/python3          # <- Anaconda
   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3 # <- python3 for OSX
   /usr/local/bin/python3           # <- python3 for OSX```
   ````

As you may see, I had installed more stuff from `mac ports`, I had `python3` for Mac downloaded and installed by hands, and also I had badly installed Anaconda (it is not seen from here, but that installation had wrong access rights). Also, you may have something from `homebrew`, which I don't use. It will also appear in `/usr/local/bin`. Well, let's get started!

3. remove Anaconda: `$ rm -rf ~/anaconda3`
4. remove everything from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/`:

   `$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/`
5. remove everything from `/Applications/Python*/`, which you may installed manually:

   `$ sudo rm -rf /Applications/Python*`
6. remove all the symlinks from `/usr/local/bin`:

   `$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python*`
7. remove all packages installed by `pip` in `~/Library/Python/`: '

   `$ rm -rf ~/Library/Python/`
8. And finally, you may also remove all `port`-related files, they are in `/opt/local/bin/python*`. **WARNING: it may break some other `port` packages!** So the most accurate way to do it is to use `port` itself (but you may skip this step in order to leave untouched the other software from ports):

   `$ sudo port uninstall python*`
9. That's it! Now you have only a system `python2.7`. You can download [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos) and install it:

   `$ sh Anaconda3-*-MacOSX-x86_64.sh`
10. Now you have a new `python3`. To check this open *a new* terminal and try:

    ```
    $ python --version
    Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
    ```
11. And `matplotlib` and all the other scientific stuff like `pandas` etc is already there:

    ```
    $ python -c "import matplotlib as mpl; print(mpl.__version__)"
    2.2.2
    ```

Comment: I ended up with a messy Python installation on Mac by having version installed by Anaconda, Homebrew, Python.org, along with the system version. It didn't help that I originally had different versions and then tried to upgrade to 3.9 and then downgrade to 3.7.

I followed Many guides on how to cleanup different versions on Mac, but this one was what worked at the end, being the most comprehensive I found.

I now use Pyenv from this guide (https://www.ianmaddaus.com/post/manage-multiple-versions-python-mac/#homebrew---pyenv) and it works!

Comment: These instructions are incomplete. After all these steps, I expect Python3 to not be recognized as a command. Instead I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3: No such file or directory`. Even installing python 39 after that (the version I need) and using port to select it as python3, I still get that error. I really need python REMOVED.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice to keep it 'clean' is to use virtual environments. You can use `conda` to do it.

From terminal run:

```
conda create -n envs_name python=3.6
```

for example.

After that you need to activate it, this is like saying "do the following only in my virtual environment and not on the global one":

```
source activate envs_name
pip install keras
pip install tensorflow
pip install ipykernel
```

The ipykernel let's you manage your environments inside Jupyter.

It's really easy and convenient.

Comment: Thanks Diego. This is very straightforward!

Answer (score 1):

It took me hours, and I haven't "cleaned" my environment, but I was able to get Python 3, Keras, Tensorflow, and Anaconda running in a Jupyter notebook by following these steps:

1. Delete Anaconda from computer
2. Install Anaconda from the web
3. Install Python 3 from the web
4. `Pip install Keras` from Terminal (*for some reason Keras wasn't shown in Anaconda Navigator, as recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47478884/896802)*)
5. `Pip install Tensorflow` from Terminal
6. Open `Jupyter Notebook` from Terminal

Answer (score 0):

I got this error "no module named Keras'. I was doing !pip install keras and !pip install tensorflow (in that order) from Jupyter Notebook. After I did the following the error went away.

1. Opened CMDexe prompt from Anaconda navigator
2. pip install Tensorflow
3. pip install Keras

Now in jupyternotebook from keras import Sequential worked fine