# clean up python versions mac osx

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I tried to run a python script on my mac computer, but I ended up in troubles as it needed to install pandas as a dependency.

I tried to get this dependency, but to do so I installed different components like brew, pip, wget and others including different versions of python using brew, .pkg package downloaded from python.org.

In the end, I was not able to run the script anyway.

Now I would like to sort out the things and have only one version of python (3 probably) working correctly.

Can you suggest me the way how to get the overview what I have installed on my computer and how can I clean it up?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean iPython environment so I can start over with Jupyter and Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493806/how-to-clean-ipython-environment-so-i-can-start-over-with-jupyter-and-python-3-x)

Answer (score 4):

Use `brew list` to see what you've installed with Brew. And `Brew Uninstall` as needed. Likewise, review the logs from `wget` to see where it installed things. Keep in mind that MacOS uses Python 2.7 for system critical tasks; it's baked-into the OS so don't touch it.

Anything you installed with pip is saved to the `/site-packages` directory of the Python version in which you installed it so it will disappear when you remove that version of Python.

The .pkg files installed directly into your `Applications` folder and can be deleted safely like any normal app.