# How should I install keras if I have anaconda?

Tags: installation, keras, anaconda, conda

Which one should I use to install keras if I have anaconda?

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

&

```
pip install --upgrade keras
```

Also, what is conda-forge? Why need to do it this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package installation of Keras in Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163150/package-installation-of-keras-in-anaconda)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantages of using `conda` rather than `pip` to install packages in your Anaconda environment(s) are that:

1. `conda` should determine what dependencies your requested package has, and install those too in one operation, and
2. you can then [keep the installed packages up to date](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/keeping-anaconda-date/) using the `conda update` command:

> **pip, PyPI, and setuptools?**
>
> None of this is going to help with updating packages that have been
>   installed from PyPI via pip, or any packages installed using python
>   setup.py install. conda list will give you some hints about the
>   pip-based Python packages you have in an environment, but it won’t do
>   anything special to update them.

The [conda-forge channel](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/community-conda-forge/) is where you can find packages that have been built for conda but are not part of the official Anaconda distribution (yet).

See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640305/how-do-i-keep-track-of-pip-installed-packages-in-an-anaconda-conda-environment?rq=1) for more detail on the two options (although bear in mind some of the answers may be out of date).

Comment: Also, this question for more about conda vs. conda-forge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857289/should-i-use-conda-or-conda-forge-when-creating-anaconda-python-environments?rq=1